# NEAR, How to implement withdraw (assembly script)

Tags: assemblyscript, near

Transfer money to a smart-contract first.
[image]

How to withdraw money from smart-contract to a sender ?
[image]

"near-sdk-as": "^3.2.1"

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

const ONE_NEAR = u128.from('1000000000000000000000000');

ContractPromiseBatch.create(sender).transfer(u128.mul(ONE_NEAR, u128.from('10')));